# Only Allow post author and "Premium" Role user to comment

Tags: comments, user-roles, author

Is there a way to make it so Everyone can see comments, But only the post author or those belonging to the Premium role can post a comment?

Could I do something like

```
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();

        if (is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID == $post->post_author)  {  comment_form();  
    } else {
     if(  $current_user->roles[0] == 'admin' || $current_user->roles[0] == 'premium' )
{ comment_form(); } endif;

     else {
        echo '<h4>You are not allowed to post comments.</h4>';
    }
```

Sorry I should have said, there are two roles, basic and premium. Both can make posts. But Only premium can comment on anyones posts, and Basic can only comment on their own posts

Comment: So could I do a check on current user is author - Display comments form, else check if current user is premium role - display comments form else display error message?

Answer (score 1):

Good news, bad news..

**Good news**
The logic behind it is really simple. You basically wrap the form inside of a simple if statement.

```
    if(condition){ 
      /*Your form here*/
    } 
    else {echo '<h4>You need to be a premium account to post comments</h4>';}
```

**Bad News**
You'll need to code in another user role. This can usually be done via a plugin. Most plugins offer documentation on how to check for a user's user-role.

So if the plugin has a function like

```
get_user_role();
```

You'd simply place that as your condition. That would look something like this:

```
  if(get_user_role() == 'premium'){ 
      /*Your form here*/
    } 
  else {echo '<h4>You need to be a premium account to post comments</h4>';}
```

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks! So what about Post author bit? So If Im the author and you're the premium role, we can both comment on my post. But Bob is a Subscriber so he cant.

Comment: Well the simplest implementation would be to just check via if statements, what the role is, who the author of the current post object is, etc. There's a million ways of implementing and developing this I'm afraid. I'd recommend getting a freelancer to land a hand if the budget permits.

Comment: To expand on @DanielFonda's comment -- you can get the author's ID from the current `$post` object; it'll be `$post->post_author`.

Answer (score 0):

In your comments.php template replace `comment_form()` with this:

```
if (current_user_can('manage_options') and current_user_can('Premium') {
   comment_form();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `comment_form()` in `comments.php` file with this code:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if(  $user->roles[0] == 'admin' || $user->roles[0] == 'premium' ){
    // show comment form
    comment_form();  
} else {
    echo '<h4>You are not allowed to post comments.</h4>';
}
```